# Printing next ASCII character in the sequence

Tags: java

I want to know that how to recognize and print next character in ASCII sequence if input is a non- string value like "space" or "!".

I know that for string value we can convert it into ASCII value by using

```
     char character = 'a';    
     int ascii = (int) character;
```

Then adding 1 to it and converting it back to char , we can get next value in the sequence .

Comment: Try `' ' + 1` and `'!' + 1` yourself. Or just look at an ASCII table.

Comment: It looks like you have the answer already, ' ' and '!' are just like any other character.
Also make sure you are not using double quotes (") when trying to add an integer value to a char, it will interpret this as a string, use single quotes. (')

Comment: @ StealthSpoder Thanks. This seems working now

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

`char character = 'a';
 int ascii = (char)((int)character+1);`

It should work. But I have haven`t tested it.

Comment: why cast it to int, then to char, then assign to int??? and BTW the author already knows that - as explained in the question.